# Remove Group Policy Permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-policy

PowerShell for Active Directory Group Policy has a couple of ways to get permissions: if you get the GPO with Get-GPO, then `$_.GetSecurityInfo()` returns permissions objects. Also, `Get-GPPermission` will get the same objects. You can write the permissions with `$_.SetSecurityInfo()` and with `Set-GPPermissions`. But how do you simply remove a permissions object, e.g. where the `$_.trustee.sidtype` is Unknown? You cannot use `Set-GPPermission`, because it requires a TargetType. 'Unknown' is not a valid TargetType. The `SetSecurityInfo()` method has no documentation that I can find. So, the question is, given the existing permissions of a GPO, how do you remove the permission object where the `$_.SidType` is Unknown?

The method to remove a permission with unknown SID is undocumented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetSecurityInfo()` returns a [`GPPermissionCollection` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/class-library/gppermissioncollection-class-microsoft-grouppolicy).

Remove the appropriate entries from the collection:

```
# fetch current permission entries
$perms = $gpo.GetSecurityInfo()

# identify trustees to be removed
$trusteesToRemove = $perms.Trustee |Where { $_.SidType -eq 'Unknown' }

# remove them from perm collection
$trusteesToRemove |ForEach-Object {
  $perms.RemoveTrustee($_.Sid)
}
```

Once modified, pass the collection object back to `SetSecurityInfo()`:

```
$gpo.SetSecurityInfo($perms)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Where do you find the 'RemoveTrustee' method? I don't see it with <code>$perms | Get-Member</code>.

Comment: @Air_ I looked at the documentation (linked in the answer). Try `Get-Member -InputObject $perms`

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed all there. I am still slightly puzzled by the logic. The GPPermissionCollection is a collection of GPPermission objects. Each permission object has a trustee, a permission level etc. You would expect that, at the collection level, I would add or remove an entire permission object.  The RemoveTrustee method seems to removing the trustee, but the trustee is not a property of the collection. It is a property of the individual GPPermissions. Is the removal of the GPPermission object then implicit? Or is something else going on?

Comment: @Air_ That's simply a choice made by whoever implemented the `GPPermissionCollection` class. Removing ACE's pertaining to a particular trustee is a common task, so the implementer of the collection decided to provide a handy method to do just that.

Comment: Fair enough, but what I meant was: is it common to have a method on a class that operates on a single property on one or more objects in the collection, rather than on the object itself? The GPPermissionsCollection also has a Remove method, which seems the more logical way to remove a GPPermission object where the Trustee.SidType is unknown.

Comment: @Air_ I fail to recognize the difference. In both cases you pass an argument to a method on the collection, and said argument is then used to identify the collection items to remove.

Comment: That's what I mean. The method is not removing an item in the collection. It is removing the trustee of an item in the collection. There must be another implicit process that says: if the Permission item no longer has a trustee, you can delete it. Because of this, the Remove method of the collection seems to make more sense. I will have to try it.
Anyway, thanks for pointing me to the GPPermissionCollection class. That's the secret to it.

Comment: @Air_ No, you're misunderstanding - `RemoveTrustee(trustee)` removes all contained ACEs where the trustee matches the `trustee` argument. The individual ACE is never modified, it's simply removed from the collection

Comment: That's what I mean. The GPPermissionCollection is a collection of GPPermissions. Each GPPermission has 5 properties, of which Trustee is one. If you remove the trustee, the permission doesn't make any sense, but it still exists, unless something else says: you can't have a permission without a trustee, so let's delete it altogether.

Comment: Last comment: it needs to be <code>$perms.RemoveTrustee($_.Sid)</code>. Otherwise, it errors with "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."

Comment: You are absolutely right. The collection is actually some kind of table structure so, when you delete a trustee, you delete ALL their permissions, not a specific permission. You cannot select a specific permission (e.g. GpoApply) and just delete that one. It will delete any permissions of the selected trustee.

Comment: @Air_ Sorry if I was unclear above, I thought "Removing ACE's pertaining to a particular trustee is a common task" made that apparent. In any case, [consult the documentation if in doubt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/class-library/gppermissioncollection-removetrustee-method-string-microsoft-grouppolicy) :)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent documentation link.

Comment: Tested and found the Remove() method works at the level of the individual permission. So, if you get the permission with the specific trustee, and/or level, you can remove it without affecting other permissions.